# Get content of a package

Tags: java, file

I want to implement a function that will take package name as input and list all the contents(only files) inside that package.

```
public List<String> getContents(String packageName) {
   ...
}
```

Example input

`packageName = com.spring.com.demo`

Expexted output

```
Class1.java
Class2.java
...
```

What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Comment: There's no universally applicable solution for this, since the design of class loaders does not provide a "list content" functionality. You can build something that works in *many* common cases, but it won't be universal. This smells like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). If you can tell us what the underlying problem is that you're trying to solve, then we can probably suggest a better solution than what you're currently working towards.

Comment: I have bunch of java classes inside a package(let's call it package1) . In another package, we have list of String that basically represents list of java classes. I want to check if all the classes exist in package1 or not?

Comment: If you want to list classes, not files, you can use https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections. I've used it in my projects as well.

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan: check "does package1 contain class X" is absolutely doable, but it's not the same as "give me a list of the content of package1".

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about java's 'classloader' system, which is a slight misnomer, in that it can also load resources other than classes. Point is, classes are a resource that are located *somewhere*, and the JVM itself needs to find them. After all, when you are running your main class and it refers to 'new Foobar()', the jvm needs to find `Foobar.class` somehow, read the bytes, and turn them into a new class definition.

Java's classloader system is generalized in two ways:

### You can call on it to find you stuff.

You can for example write:

```
MyApp.class.getResource("icons/share.png")
```

and get a URL object you can pass straight to e.g. `ImageIcon`. This way, you can ship your icons for your GUI app together with your class files, and it's completely unified: However the system is loading the classes, be it from disk, from inside a jar file, from eclipse's module system if it's an eclipse plugin, or from the network - this way you're loading your images from the same place.

### You can make your own

Let's say you want to write a system that loads classes (and other resources, like images) directly from the web. You can do that: You can make your own ClassLoaders.

### Now for the crux of the matter

That means `ClassLoader` is an abstract concept that lists which features it has. It's like any other interface / abstract class in that regard: It's a template that defines what you can do with one, so that anybody can provide you with an implementation of it.

Here's the crucial thing you must understand so that you know why *what you want is impossible* (and why the commonly called out 'reflections' library is a hack that doesn't universally work):

**The ClassLoader abstract simply has *no* `list` command.**

Hence, listing? Simply not possible. The only command it does have is 'load Resource X', X being some path-like string. *That is all it has*. The java classloader system is never in need to 'list all classes in a package', not even when there's a star import (which is just a thing `javac` knows about, at the class file level star imports aren't a thing). The JVM just needs to e.g. load resource '/java/lang/String.class' - hence, the command 'here is a path, please give me the bytes for it' is all that is neccessary.

### The solution to have lists anyway

During compilation, the abstractions *do* support 'list'. After all, the compiler really does just read java files from a directory (which supports 'list all files inside it'), you can't for example tell the compiler 'please compile all `.java` files in this `.jar` file). So, *at compile time*, you can make a list of resources.

So here's the trick: Save that in a text file and ask for the text file during runtime. Then translate each line in the text file to the full resource path and then ask for each of those. Thus, using *just* the one API call you have available to you at runtime ('load resource at path X'), you can have a list system anyway. It's just that during the compilation/build/packing step you need the tools that compile/build/pack to do some work and make you a text file with the details.

This is called the SPI (Service Provider Interface) system and java itself uses it - it's how JDBC drivers and e.g. charset implementations are found.

You can use this yourself in this three step process:

1. Define an interface or abstract class that serves as the thing 'providers' will implement/extend. Let's say it is com.ranjan.MyService`.
2. At the provider end: Write an implementation for it. Let's say it's `com.zwitserloot.ServiceImpl`.
3. During compilation, ensure that in the same place the class files end up (e.g. in the jar file for example), there's `META-INF/services/com.ranjan.Myservice` (a text file). This file contains the fully qualified class name of each 'provider' class: `com.zwitserloot.ServiceImpl` is what's on the first (and only) line.
4. At runtime: Use [`java.util.ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) and it'll take care of everything.

### Your specific use case

From comments it seems like you don't really need to 'list classes', you have a bunch of classes and need to know if they are 'valid', for some definition of 'valid'. You can either just `Class.forName` them, though this will also initialize them (run its static initializers). Alternatively, you can run `YourOwnClass.class.getResource("com.spring.com.demo.Class1.class")`, and check that [A] you get an actual resource (and not `null`, indicating it doesn't exist), and [B] do whatever validation you want to do on this. For example, toss it through bytebuddy or ASM or some other class format editor and check if it can parse it.

Comment: Thanks @rzwitserloot for providing such deep understanding.